# How to implement one loop with different frequencies

Tags: c++

Assume the following `while` loop runs at 1kHz. What is the proper way to run another piece of code inside this loop but with different frequency (i.e. say 500Hz) without multithreading.

```
while (1){ // running 1kHz (i.e. outer loop)
      do stuff

      if (){ // running 500Hz (i.e. inner loop)
         do another stuff
      }
}
```

Another question is assume the outer loop runs at the maximum speed of the CPU, is it possible to run the inner loop at a percentage of outer loop (i.e. 50% of outer loop).

Comment: I think you mean [e.g. rather than i.e.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/ie-vs-eg-abbreviation-meaning-usage-difference) Perhaps you could simply maintain a counter that is incremented on each iteration of the outer loop and then if it's evenly divisible by 2 (or 3 or whatever) do the inner stuff.

Comment: Add a counter that is incremented once per iteration. Execute the code you want to run half the time when the counter is even or odd depending on if you want it to run on the first iteration or the second.

Comment: Wait... You want a single iteration of the inner loop to take 2 mS, but a single iteration of the outer loop -- which includes *all* iterations of the inner loop -- to take only 1 mS?

Comment: Run the 500Hz stuff on every second iteration of the 1kHz loop.  For example, introduce a `bool` that is flipped every second iteration of the outer loop, and only execute the 500Hz "stuff" when that `bool` is `true` (or `false` - you pick).   For more general frequencies (or if you want multiple bits of "stuff" each at different frequencies) use a counter of some form.

Comment: If you are using `while(1)` without break then how would that ever run at 1kHz? Normally you have a function that represents one iteration of the loop and then something extern, like a timer interrupt, that calls the function with 1kHz timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is something like this:

```
int counter = 0;

while (1) {
  // do stuff

  if (++counter == 2) { // inner loop
     counter = 0;
     
     // do other stuff
  }
}
```

Note that in a spin-loop like this there's no guarantee that the outer loop will run at 1kHz; it will run at a speed determined by the CPU speed and the amount of work that occurs within the loop.  If you really need exactly 1kHz execution, you'll probably want to program a timer-interrupt instead.  What is guaranteed is that the code inside the inner `if()` block will be executed on every second iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Could also do `unsigned counter = 0;` then `if (++counter % 2) { ... }`. No need to reset the counter, there is no way for it to get out of sync, etc. `% 2` will be optimized out to `& 1` anyway.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: but for other divisors (as 3), without the reset, you would have an "error" when counter reachs its upper limit (the same way that `random() % range` is biased).

Comment: @Jarod42 you reckon that would matter when we're talking about ~kHz level bluntness?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili with respect to performance it probably wouldn't be noticeable, but what if the state-logic of the program depends on the inner-if code running in a precisely deterministic pattern?  In that case, violating that assumption could cause the program to misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```c
unsigned int counter = 0;

while (1) {
  // do stuff
  counter+=1;
  if ((counter%2) == 0) { // inner loop

     
     // do other stuff
  }
}
```